# Is there way I can replicate a 502 gateway timeout error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am trying to create a page that will take more than 600 seconds to load. Do you have any idea on what to create for this to happen? Or just anything to generate the 502 gateway timeout error.

Comment: You want to create a 502 server response from a client side script...?

Comment: Create it how? The 502 would need to come from the backend, nothing on the front end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

502 is Status code for Bad Gateway, not Gateway timeout. 504 is the code you are looking for.

Here's a Gateway timeout with 5000 milliseconds: https://httpstat.us/504?sleep=5000

One for 600 seconds: https://httpstat.us/504?sleep=600000

Comment: On your Web Client, implement something like this:
    `const http = new XMLHttpRequest()`
    `http.open("GET", "https://httpstat.us/504?sleep=5000")`
    `http.send()`
    `http.onload = () => console.log(http.responseText)`


If this doesn't answer your question, maybe you should try to detail a bit more what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This must be done server-side.
Depending on the backend language you are using, you have the following options:

1. Return a 502 HTTP response (this can also be done directly in Apache or NGINX)
2. Simulate a long response with a "sleep" function (this depends on what backend you are using)
3. Infinite loop for testing purposes, but I couldn't recommend that!